# Issue with webdriver installation

Tags: python, ubuntu, docker

I am using this to install chrome webdriver but it stopped working.

command for `dockerfile`

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y gnupg wget curl unzip --no-install-recommends && \
    wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list && \
    apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable && \
    CHROMEVER=$(google-chrome --product-version | grep -o "[^\.]*\.[^\.]*\.[^\.]*") && \
    DRIVERVER=$(curl -s "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_$CHROMEVER") && \
    wget -q --continue "http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$DRIVERVER/chromedriver_linux64.zip" && \
    unzip chromedriver* && \
    pwd && ls
```

any idea how to fix this?
Thanks